# How to update a local table built from dataframe by joining to another local table?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I have a two local tables and I want to update the first one based on the value from the second one by join them using sql like this and store it in another local table

```
val a=spark.sql(""" UPDATE PC
SET PC.ComponentCode = 'UN'
,PC.LegacyCategoryCode = 'UN'
FROM tbllabortemp PC
JOIN (
            SELECT CL.ContractScheduleId
                ,CL.WarehouseId
                ,CL.ComponentCode
            FROM tblContractLineitemUnicorn CL
            INNER JOIN tbllabortemp CP ON CP.ContractSchedule_ID = CL.ContractScheduleId
                AND CP.warehouse_id = CL.WarehouseId
                AND CP.Component_Code = CL.ComponentCode
            GROUP BY CL.ContractScheduleId
                ,CL.WarehouseId
                ,CL.ComponentCode
            HAVING SUM(CL.LineItemTotalPurchasedUnits) < 1
            ) LI ON PC.ContractScheduleID = LI.ContractScheduleId
            AND PC.warehouse_id = LI.WarehouseId
            AND PC.Component_Code = LI.ComponentCode """)

a.createOrReplaceTempView("MergeTable")
```

but it is giving me a "mismatched input 'FROM' expecting ", Please help on this.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the syntax of Delta lake `UPDATE` statements

```
UPDATE [db_name.]table_name [AS alias] SET col1 = value1 [, col2 = value2 ...] [WHERE predicate]
```

Below are the limitations of using `UPDATE` statement in Databricks

```
Note

The following types of subqueries are not supported:

Nested subqueries, that is, a subquery inside another subquery
A NOT IN subquery inside an OR, for example, a = 3 OR b NOT IN (SELECT c from t)
In most cases, you can rewrite NOT IN subqueries using NOT EXISTS. We recommend using NOT EXISTS whenever possible, as UPDATE with NOT IN subqueries can be slow.
```

Looks like you would need to re-write your query before there is no `FROM` in UPDATE STATEMENT syntax as well as nested subqueries and JOINS are not supported

```
val inner = spark.sql("""SELECT CL.ContractScheduleId
                ,CL.WarehouseId
                ,CL.ComponentCode
            FROM tblContractLineitemUnicorn CL
            INNER JOIN tbllabortemp CP ON CP.ContractSchedule_ID = CL.ContractScheduleId
                AND CP.warehouse_id = CL.WarehouseId
                AND CP.Component_Code = CL.ComponentCode
            GROUP BY CL.ContractScheduleId
                ,CL.WarehouseId
                ,CL.ComponentCode
            HAVING SUM(CL.LineItemTotalPurchasedUnits) < 1
            """)

val a=spark.sql(""" UPDATE tbllabortemp as PC
SET PC.ComponentCode = 'UN'
,PC.LegacyCategoryCode = 'UN'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ContractScheduleId from inner CL where PC.ContractScheduleID = LI.ContractScheduleId
            AND PC.warehouse_id = LI.WarehouseId
            AND PC.Component_Code = LI.ComponentCode """) 


a.createOrReplaceTempView("MergeTable")
```

Here is the link to the Azure Databricks documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/update

## UPDATE based on new requirements

```
scala> val initial = Seq((1,"AB"),(2,"XY"),(3,"MN"),(4,"PQ")).toDF("id","value")
ivysettings.xml file not found in HIVE_HOME or HIVE_CONF_DIR,/etc/hive/conf.dist/ivysettings.xml will be used
initial: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, value: string]

scala> val final_val = Seq((2,"XY"),(3,"MN")).toDF("id","value")
final_val: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, value: string]

scala> initial.join(final_val,initial("id") === final_val("id"),"left_outer").show(10)
+---+-----+----+-----+                                                          
| id|value|  id|value|
+---+-----+----+-----+
|  1|   AB|null| null|
|  2|   XY|   2|   XY|
|  3|   MN|   3|   MN|
|  4|   PQ|null| null|
+---+-----+----+-----+

val init_alias = initial.select( col("id").as("id_init"),  col("value").as("value_init"))

val mod_alias = final_val.select(col("id").as("id_mod"),  col("value").as("value_mod"))

init_alias.join(mod_alias,init_alias("id_init") === mod_alias("id_mod"),"left_outer").createOrReplaceTempView("table")


spark.sql("select id_init as id, CASE WHEN value_mod is null THEN 'UN' ELSE value_int END as value from table ").show()

+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|   UN|
|  2|   XY|
|  3|   MN|
|  4|   UN|
+---+-----
```

Comment: I tried using that way without sub-queries but the problem is my tables are local tables derived from dataframe not delta tables, I think databricks does not support updating local tables, it supports update on delta tables

It gives me this error when I execute that statement "UPDATE destination only supports Delta sources.", Do you know how to change local tables that are created by a statement like this "a.createOrReplaceTempView("MergeTable")" into delta tables.

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle dataframes which are not delta tables. If this was helpful do accept the answer.